# Is it absolutely necessary to load pointers to OpenGL functions

Tags: c++, opengl

I started learning OpenGL from online tutorials and some of them have made use of glad and GLEW.
I read that it is necessary to load pointers to OpenGL functions either manually or with a loading library.

But some tutorials only use glut and no pointers are used to load the functions like glbegin

Comment: Immediate mode ([Legacy OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL)) OpenGL functions (like `glBegin` ) may be provided by "gl.h". "Moden" OpenGL functions have to be loaded by a loder like glad or gelw.

Comment: [Depends on the OS and which GL version you're targeting](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Load_OpenGL_Functions).

Answer (score -2):

There are two different parts of OpenGL you witnessed: The OpenGL legacy and modern api.
The tutorials you refer to as not using pointers are using the legacy functions, which are very simple, but also slow.

OpenGL legacy functions:

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glVertex2d(-0.5, -0.5);
glVertex2d( 0.5, -0.5);
glVertex2d( 0.5,  0.5);
glVertex2d(-0.5,  0.5);
glEnd();
```

Those functions are simple and slow: You basically send every single vertex to the GPU separately.

Modern pipeline: (Incomplete code sample from LearnOpenGL.com)

```
float vertices[] = {
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // left  
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // right 
     0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f  // top   
}; 

unsigned int VBO, VAO;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
glBindVertexArray(VAO);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); 
glBindVertexArray(0); 

while(true) {

    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // draw our first triangle
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}
```

Using this modern pipeline you have all vertices already in an array and you send the whole array to the GPU with glBufferData(), which is what you meant with pointers - it's actually all just arrays.

This way all the data gets sent in one big chunk of data and all of those triangles are drawn with a single draw call: Using this method one can draw tens of thousands of triangles every frame!

But there is more: (Again, incomplete code sample from LearnOpenGL.com)

```
float vertices[] = {
     0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,  // top right
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  // bottom right
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  // bottom left
    -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f   // top left 
};
unsigned int indices[] = {  // note that we start from 0!
    0, 1, 3,  // first Triangle
    1, 2, 3   // second Triangle
};
unsigned int VBO, VAO, EBO;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);
glBindVertexArray(VAO);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); 
glBindVertexArray(0); 

while (true) {

    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // draw our first triangle
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}
```

This code is using vertex indexing, which is the commonly used method. Without this you would have to specify three vertices with all data for every triangle, meaning that if several faces use the same vertex, it is duplicated. But with this method you only specify all vertices once and in a separate index buffer you specify which faces should use which vertices, you basically say: 
I want those vertices at those positions and then i want a triangle from vertex 1 to vertex 7 to vertex 89.

But back to the topic, the last method - index buffering - is the most widely used and probably the one you should also be using. Yes, it is a lot more complicated and you need vertex arrays, vertex buffers, index buffers, vertex shaders, fragment shaders and so on, but when taking a look at [LearnOpenGL](https://learnopengl.com) you can follow along these tutorials, they explain everything in detail and you can also take a look at the source code in the examples.

Also, you probably meant model loaders like for loading .obj files, but loading the model is independent from the rendering pipeline - you would also need that if you were using the legacy functions (which you shouldn't)

And there is no difference between glad and glut, theyre both headers providing the OpenGL functions - just different projects with the same functionality